# How to add a mean point to a scatter plot for each cluster individually?

Tags: r

I have plotted the following data in a scatter plot..

```
X   Y
90  3
3   0
90  4
30  0
14  0
70  1
20  3
90  5
21  2
15  0
82  2
1   0
1   0
```

and performed k-means cluster analysis with k = 2

```
results = kmeans(data,2)

plot(data$X , data$Y,
     xlab = "X" , ylab = "Y",
     col = results$cluster , pch = 19)
```

This gives me the following scatter plot 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEewK.png)

I have tried the following line of code, but it only shows me the mean of the entire dataset.

```
points(mean(data$X), mean(data$Y))
```

I want to know how to show the means of each separate cluster. Thank you

Comment: How about `points(results$centers,col = c("black","red"),pch=10)` ?

Comment: @maydin That worked perfectly, could you explain the logic behind it in an answer?

Comment: There is no a deep logic actually. After you run your `kmeans()` function, you reach the clusters by typing `results$cluster` , similarly inside the `kmeans()` function, you can reach the centroids which are nothing but the mean of the clusters by typing `results$centers`. So, `$centers`, `$clusters` etc are all inside the 'kmeans()'. After running the cluster algorithm just type `results` and run it, you will see at the bottom of the screen what you can use like   `$centers`, `$clusters`. You will find additional outputs that can be called.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work for any given number of clusters:

```
## Your code:
results = kmeans(data,2)
plot(data$X , data$Y,
     xlab = "X" , ylab = "Y",
     col = results$cluster , pch = 19)
## Add a cluster info in the data:
data$cluster <- results$cluster
## Compute the center of each cluster:
clusters <- split(data[, 1:2], data$cluster)
centers <- lapply(clusters, FUN = colMeans)
## Plot those centers:
for (k in 1:length(clusters)) {
    points(x = centers[[k]][1],
           y = centers[[k]][2],
           col = k,
           pch = 1
           )
}
```

(This solution only uses functions from "base R".)